# git-svn import only branch

Tags: git, git-svn

I want to import only 1 branch from my svn repo as a git repository. So I want the contents of that branch to become the master. I don't want anything else in the repository. I also don't really want to be able to commit to the original svn repo. Actually, I don't want anything to happen to my svn repo.

Example:

```
branches
  branch1
  branch2
  some-branch
    project
```

so I want content of the `project` folder to become my master branch. How can I do that?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

looks like there are branches that were merged into my branch, and git-svn can not find history because it looks in

branches/some-branch/project/branches/branch1

it thinks that my remote branch is the root. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Define the new branch in .git/config :

```
[svn-remote "release-branch"]
        url = svn+ssh://user@yourdomain.com/source/branches/mono-2-2/mcs
        fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn-release-branch
```

2) Import the SVN branch. SVN_BRANCHED_REVISION is the the revision when the branch happened in SVN.

```
[~]$ git svn fetch release-branch -r SVN_BRANCHED_REVISION
```

3) Hook up a local Git branch to the remote branch:

```
[~]$ git branch --track release git-svn-release-branch
```

5) Checkout and update

```
[~]$ git checkout release
[~]$ git svn rebase
```

Comment: Thanks. But now it says it couldn't find revmap for other branches that were reintegrated into this branch. because it thinks this branch is the root :(