# git-svn "Couldn't find revmap for"

Tags: git, git-svn

I followed this tutorial:
http://www.beletsky.net/2011/06/how-to-start-using-git-in-svn-based.html

I did this and it worked fine for a while i could rebase and dcommit and all.

But then I got an error when doing "git svn rebase":
"Couldn't find revmap for"
It seems that git-svn suddenly thinks that my branch is the svn trunk...

This might be the answer:
[git-svn import only branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291347/git-svn-import-only-branch)

But I am simply not smart enough to unserstand it.

**Edit**
What I did between the "git svn rebase" that worked and the one giving an error was create a branch and stash a little...

**Edit 2 **
This looks useful as well:
[git svn clone > git svn rebase > Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965486/git-svn-clone-git-svn-rebase-unable-to-determine-upstream-svn-information-fro)

Comment: This question frames the "Couldn't find revmap for" error in terms of rebase. For a more general framing, and/or the discussion of that error arising during "git svn fetch", see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592497/git-svn-couldnt-find-revmap-what-does-it-mean/10021625#10021625

Answer (score 1):

I seem to only be able to rebase one svn tree at a time. My workflow is currently:

```
git checkout master
git svn rebase   ## fetches revisions that touched svn trunk
git rebase master localdevbranch

git checkout Release_1.0
git svn rebase  ## fetches revisions from svn branch/Release_1.0
git rebase Release_1.0 patch-1.1-dev
```

But, like you, I imagine there must be a better way to do this...  I get lots of revmap errors as well when checking out the svn branch code (but not trunk, for some reason).  Seems like one big 'git svn fetch' would get everything, and rebase all the tracking branches at once. One at a time is tedious.

Anyone?